# Steps to read the text file into specific columns of JTable using biojava

Tags: java, jtable, biojava

Here is a typical input `.txt` file (also called as fasta file):

```
>contig00001  length=586   numreads=4
CGGGAAATTATCcGCGCCTTCACCGCCGCCGGTTCCACCGACGAACGGATACTGCGtGaa
ggCCGCGATCCCGTCggaCGGAAAaCGCCcTGGCCCGGGAaCATACCGTTCGGGCCGCCA
AGTGTTATAGCCGGACCACTTGTCAGAACATTTCCaaTCCGAAGATGTGAGTtCGGAAGg
TAAAAGCCCGACAAGTTGCGCGgTGAATTTACCTTtACcGCACGATATGCGTCCGTATTA
AaGAAAaGTTCGAAATTATCAGTAAGGCCGACCTGAAaGCTGACCGGGAGTTCAACAAAA
TCTGCATCACCcGGgTCACGGTCGAAATTGCTGTACGCGGCGCTGAACGTAAATTCACCC
TTTcTAAGGGTGTCGCcGTCGTAAACCGTAAaCAaGCCGGTAGCGCCGCCCATCGGGCCG
CCGGTACCAACCGTCGGTGCCGTGTTTCTtGCATCATTGTCCGATCGAGCGTTCTCGTCC
GCTTGTGCAAaTCCTGCAaTAGCTAACGTGAAAACGATCAGAGCTGTTGTAAATACTCTA
TAAGCGAGATTCATCACATTCCTCcGCCGAAATAAAAAGTTAATTt

>contig00002  length=554   numreads=4
TGCGCCAaCCGCGCTCTtCATAAaTGGGCACTGCTCCCGATGGCCgACTCGGGCGGTTCG
CCATGAGATCTTTGCCtACCcAGgAaCtCACcACCAAGTCTGATTGCTGTGTGTTTtCTT
CAAGTCCCTATTTCTATTCtCTTtAATGGAACCCGTAGGAAACCCGTGTAGGACGCGGGA
aCCGCACTTgAAGGGGGAGGCGCGGGGTACCGGtCCGGGAACGTACGGGTACCGGCGGGG
gAGGGGAGGGGGACCgCTCCGGGAAGGCCAGGGGACGGATTGGGGAAGGgCGGGTACCGA
AGCGGGgAAaTGGGggAaCcGGCGAGAGGGTTCCTCGCTAAGTGGGGGAAATaGGGGAAA
GGTTGACCAGTGGTtCCCcGCTCTCGTAACATGCCTCAGATAGCGCCATCCGCTGTACCT
GGtcaggtcGctggcaacttcggccgagcaggtgaacccgaaaggtgagggtcagtgtga
cacaccaaccgaacaccgacgaggcaagcgtaggagccggcgtggccgcgcccggcggcg
ctgaggactcctcg
```

Code to read the sequence may be found [here](http://www.biojava.org/wiki/BioJava%3aCookbook%3aSeqIO%3aReadGESBiojavax).

It gives the proper output, as shown below with tab seperation:

```
contig00001   586   52.38
contig00002   554   62.45
```

The problem is that I developed a form in NetBeans that consists of a `JTable` having 5 columns i.e:

```
"contigID","Description","Organism","Sequence_length","Gc_percentage"
```

and a `JTextArea`. I want to display the above output in the `JTable` columns, while the other columns remain empty; and when I click 'contig00001' in `JTable`, then respective sequence like "CGGGAAAT...." should be displayed in the `JTextArea`.

How can I do that? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell me, what *exactly* are you stuck on?  I don't see any Swing/JTable or table model code in your snippet of code above.

Comment: This appears to be the same homework assignment as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214468/how-to-read-the-given-text-file

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to extend `AbstractTableModel`, as discussed in [*Creating a Table Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Addendum: By listening for a [*user selection*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), you can determine which row was selected and update your `JTextArea` accordingly.

Addendum: Because data retrieval may be prtotracted, [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) offers a safe way to mutate the `TableModel`. Here's a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're stuck on. If it's adding data to the JTable, I'd consider creating a DefaultTableModel object, constructing it with the correct column header Strings in an array, with 0 rows of data, and then adding rows of data as you read through your files. The JTable tutorial should help you do all of this. Once you have your table model created, you can add it to your JTable easily via its setModel method.

Comment: +1 for `DefaultTableModel`. Because these files can be _huge_, I was wary; but the bulk goes in the `JTextArea`.

Comment: @trashgod: thanks, and I've already 1+'d you for your AbstractTableModel and info on user selection. Still no word from the OP though on exactly where he's stuck.